# why should a clone method not invoke any nonfinal methods on the clone under construction

Tags: java, final

I was reading effective java 2nd edition and came across this paragraph. When does the following action arise and why dos it create problem?

> Like a constructor, a clone method should not invoke any nonfinal
>   methods on the clone under construction (Item 17). If clone invokes an
>   overridden method, this method will execute before the subclass in
>   which it is defined has had a chance to fix its state in the clone,
>   quite possibly leading to corruption in the clone and the original.
>   Therefore the put(key, value) method discussed in the previous
>   paragraph should be either final or private. (If it is private, it is
>   presumably the “helper method” for a nonfinal public method.)

Note: I didn't know that when we override a method a() and parent contructor used method a(). When we do super() from subclass new a() is called instead of parent's a(). I understand same problem happens with clone()

Comment: I've added an example to illustrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because a `protected` or `public` non-final method is overridable by a subclass, which is the footstep to initialization problems. Say the overriden method tries to access a field before it gets initialized, you would get a `NullPointerException`. Say it calls another method that relies on a specific state of the object that is not guaranteed before full initialization, it would result in an even more subtle error or incorrectness of the program.

All I'm saying is already in your book though, so let's add a concrete example:

```
public SpaceShip {
    private double oilLevelInLitres;
    private String model;

    public SpaceShip(double oilLevelInLitres, String model) {
       this.oilLevelInLitres = oilLevelInLitres;
       displayOilLevel();
       this.model = model;
    }

    public void displayOilLevel() {
       System.out.println("Oil level is currently " + oilLevelInLitres + " litres");
    }
}

public SpaceShipWithSecondaryReservoir {    
    public SpaceShip(double oilLevelInLitres, double secondaryReservoirOilLevelInLitres, String oilLevelInLitres) {
        super(oilLevelInLitres, oilLevelInLitres);
        this.secondaryReservoirOilLevelInLitres = secondaryReservoirOilLevelInLitres;
    }

    public void displayOilLevel() {
        System.out.println("Model " + model + " oil level is currently " + oilLevelInLitres + 
            " litres and " + secondaryReservoirOilLevelInLitres + " litres in the seconday reservoir");
    }
}

public Main() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // will print "Model null oil level is currently 17.0 litres and 5.0 litres in 
        // the secondary reservoir"
        new SpaceShipWithSecondaryReservoir(17, 5, "Falcon-3X"); 
    }
}
```

In this example you could argue that the parent class could have initialize the `model` name before calling the method, and you're right, but at the moment the programer wrote the parent class constructor he was making the assumption that the display method would not need any other state than the oil level.

This is a programming error that was avoidable by calling thhe display method at the end of the constructor, but in more complicated cases it would not be that trivial and obvious. Calling an overridable method in a constructor exposes you to a class of mistakes which does not exist when you only call final or private methods.

Comment: The example you wrote is not involving the clone() method. In what way does this principle apply to the clone() method? If we do as suggested by the book, we should make a temporary clone with super.clone() and then adjust it with the proper setter methods. If we call an overridden method in the clone() method, they will be called on the object returned by a SubClass clone = (SubClass) super.clone(). After the previous statement the object should be already in a stable state. How can we craft an example in which the overridden method used in a clone leads to a unstable state? Thanks :)

Comment: You can use exactly the same technique as in my answer. You subclass your `Cloneable` class, you add a field in the subclass in addition to the fields of the superclass, you call an overridable method from the `clone` method of the parent class and you override this method in the subclass to use the field that is only present in the subclass. Since the parent class doesn't know about this field there's no way it could set it up before calling the overridable method that will therefore fail with an NPE.

Comment: can you have a look in this code and see what's wrong?
https://gist.github.com/acejazz/3b7a1bc0d788bc91cccd8907225e1156 I'm not able to throw the NPE.

Comment: I commented on your Gist :)

Comment: I did that and it actually worked. But is that NPE related to the clone method and overriding? I mean, if you add that line, you have the NPE even if you don't clone any object and even if you are not overriding any method. You are simply using something before being initialized and that can happen at any point in our code, without involving clone and overriding.

Comment: It never happens that an object is partially initialized outside of a constructor or a clone method. If you're executing code in any other method, you expect the object to be fully initialized, unless programming errors have been made.  Overridable construction logic is dangerous because it allows subclasses to alter private state from the superclass or the superclass to dereference private fields of the subclass before they are initialized.

Comment: Therefore what does "If clone invokes an overridden method, this method will execute before the subclass in which it is defined has had a chance to fix its state in the clone" mean? A clone method will be always executed when the constructor has executed, thus the state will be already stable. Unless the clone is the only method to create new instances and the constructor is not able to return a stable instance. Am I right?

Comment: Not really, clone methods don't always call a constructor. It's probably bad practice because mutable is bad, but I'm guessing it's not unusual to have setters in clone implementations.